# Nginx PHP setup - No input file specified

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx, digital-ocean

I know it's a very much known issue. I have tried almost everything but couldn't fix yet.

Intent is to create a blog using php/wordpress with already existing nginx as web server. Nginx is already being used as a web server to a Rails app.

Here's what my nginx.conf looks like

```
user  centos;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/centos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@tripshelf/gems/passenger-5.1.2;
    passenger_ruby /home/centos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@tripshelf/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    rails_env staging;

    server {
        listen       80;

        server_name  xx.xxx.xxx.xx;
        location / {
            root   /data/staging-tiger/current/public/;
            passenger_enabled on;
            index index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
           root           /data/blog/;
           index          index.php index.html index.htm;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

I followed digital ocean's [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6) on how to install LEMP stack.

After installation, when I hit http://example.com/info.php I get

```
 No input file specified
```

On further research, I tried:

1. Setting the right permissions to document root - /data/blog with proper execute permissions to /, /data, /data/blog and /data/blog/info.php
2. php location block has its own index and root directives.
3. Nginx is running as centos user. Here's the output of `ps aux | grep nginx`

`root     11510  0.0  0.1  53984  1320 ?        Ss   07:06   0:00 nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx`

`centos   11513  0.0  0.2  54364  2612 ?        S    07:06   0:00 nginx: worker process`

`centos   13471  0.0  0.0 103312   876 pts/1    S+   07:42   0:00 grep nginx`

4. User and Group are set to `centos` in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` file.

   `user = centos`

   `group = centos`
5. Running stat on Document root shows

File: /data/blog/info.php

```
Size: 20  Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d Inode: 525709   Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  500/  centos)   Gid: (  500/  centos)
Access: 2017-10-19 16:47:54.528000890 +0000
Modify: 2017-10-19 16:47:54.528000890 +0000
Change: 2017-10-20 06:18:28.000001084 +0000
```

I have been wrapping my head around this but no breakthrough so far. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The guide followed wasn't for WordPress, so the nginx config is probably a little off.

Try amending the PHP block, notice the added fastcgi_param lines.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /data/blog/;
    index          index.php index.html index.htm;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

If that fails, there might be something you can use from either
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

Or the more detailed
https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Also, it should be generating the errors in the nginx log file.

```
clear && tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```